# Unable to fetch _source dictionary key-val from elastic client search response

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, visual-studio-2015, nest

I am trying to access the hits _source dictionary to load into a db.
hits returns null, what am I doing wrong ?

Notes:
searchResponse is returned with the JSON data, and the debuginformation confirms it.

However, the Hit and the _Source class and the underlying data variables are not accessible and variable hits returns null.

The below code of the local variable in debug mode shows the data.
If needed then I can include more data or an image of the local variables or debug information window if that would help the scope of the problem.

Thanks in advance.

Tried accessing the _source key value pairs with searchResponse.Documents and foreach statement to access the elements inside hits. But was not able to access _source key value pairs.

```cs
/*Declared classes in visual studio console application for c#:
.NET framework 4.5*/

class Program
{

    public class Doc
    {
        public int took { get; set; }
        public bool timed_out { get; set; }
        public _Shards _shards { get; set; }
        public Hits hits { get; set; }
    }

    public class _Shards
    {
        public int total { get; set; }
        public int successful { get; set; }
        public int skipped { get; set; }
        public int failed { get; set; }
    }

    public class Hits
    {
        public int total { get; set; }
        public float max_score { get; set; }
        public Hit[] hits { get; set; }
    }

    public class Hit
    {
        public string _index { get; set; }
        public string _type { get; set; }
        public string _id { get; set; }
        public float _score { get; set; }
        public _Source _source { get; set; }
    }

    public class _Source
    {
        public int duration { get; set; }
        public string group_id { get; set; }
        public DateTime var_time { get; set; }
        public string var_name { get; set; }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var uri = new Uri("http://domain_name.val.url:9203/");
        var pool = new SingleNodeConnectionPool(uri);
        var connectionSettings = new ConnectionSettings(pool)
                                .DisableDirectStreaming();
        var resolver = new IndexNameResolver(connectionSettings);
        var client = new ElasticClient(connectionSettings);

        if (!client.IndexExists("test_index").Exists)
        {
            client.CreateIndex("test_index");
        }

        var searchResponse = client.Search<Doc>(s => s
        .Index("test_index")
        .AllTypes()
        .Size(1)
        .Query(q => q
        .MatchAll())
        .TypedKeys(null)
        .SearchType(Elasticsearch.Net.SearchType.DfsQueryThenFetch)
        .Scroll("30s")
      );
    MessageBox.Show("searchResponse.DebugInformation=" + searchResponse.DebugInformation);
    }
}
```

---

Elastic Search sample URL data:

```js
{
  "took" : 12,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 2700881,
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "test_index",
        "_type" : "doc",
        "_id" : "R22224!!5333e7e4-9ee3-45f4-9dc3-2a8b8d8cdcf8",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "duration" : 14986283,
          "group_id" : "com",
          "var_time" : "2018-04-24T17:05:13.082+02:00",
          "var_name" : "2",
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**Update:**
Someone internally in the office suggested using the following code solution and then iterating through the key value pair.

```
        var searchResponse = client.Search<Doc>(s => s
            .Index("test_index")
            .AllTypes()
            .Size(10)
            .Query(q => q
            .MatchAll())
            .TypedKeys(null)
            .SearchType(Elasticsearch.Net.SearchType.DfsQueryThenFetch)
            .Scroll("30s")
            .RequestConfiguration(r=>r
            .DisableDirectStreaming()
            )
            );
        var raw = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(searchResponse.ApiCall.ResponseBodyInBytes);  
        JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        jss.MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue;
        var pairs = jss.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, dynamic>>(raw);
```

Comment: could you please add more information, so it would be more clear what the problem you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you've misunderstood the API of the client; you don't need to declare `_Shards`, `Hit`, `Hits`, `_Source`, etc. the client takes care of deserializing these parts of the Elasticsearch API for you.

The only part that you need to define is a POCO that will map to the JSON object in each `"_source"` field in the response, i.e.

```
{
  "duration" : 14986283,
  "group_id" : "com",
  "var_time" : "2018-04-24T17:05:13.082+02:00",
  "var_name" : "2",
}
```

which it looks like the `_Source` POCO does (although I'd be inclined to give it a more meaningful name!). Let's just call it `MyDocument` for now.

With `MyDocument` defined as

```
public class MyDocument
{
    [PropertyName("duration")]
    public int Duration { get; set; }

    [PropertyName("group_id")]
    public string GroupId { get; set; }

    [PropertyName("var_time")]
    public DateTime Time { get; set; }

    [PropertyName("var_name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

A simple search would be

```
var pool = new SingleNodeConnectionPool(new Uri("http://localhost:9200"));

var settings = new ConnectionSettings(pool)
    .DefaultMappingFor<MyDocument>(m => m
        .IndexName("test_index")
        .TypeName("doc")
    );

var client = new ElasticClient(settings);

var searchResponse = client.Search<MyDocument>();

// A collection of the top 10 matching documents
var documents = searchResponse.Documents;
```

The `DefaultMappingFor<MyDocument>(...)` will use the index name `"test_index"` and type name "`doc`" whenever the generic type of document is `MyDocument`, and they are not explicitly defined in the request.

The above search generates the following query to Elasticsearch

```
POST http://localhost:9200/test_index/doc/_search
{}
```

Now, it looks like you want to use the Scroll API to return *all* matching documents. To do this with the Scroll API, you would write a loop to keep making scroll requests so long as documents are being returned

```
var searchResponse = client.Search<MyDocument>(s => s
    .Size(1000)
    .Scroll("30s")
);

while (searchResponse.Documents.Any())
{
    foreach (var document in searchResponse.Documents)
    {
        // do something with this set of 1000 documents
    }

    // make an additional request
    searchResponse = client.Scroll<MyDocument>("30s", searchResponse.ScrollId);
}

// clear scroll id at the end
var clearScrollResponse = client.ClearScroll(c => c.ScrollId(searchResponse.ScrollId));
```

There is a `ScrollAll` observable helper that you can use to make this easier to write, and that [parallelizes the operation using `sliced_scroll`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-scroll.html#sliced-scroll). The same operation as above, but using `ScrollAll`

```cs
// set to number of shards in targeted indices
var numberOfSlices = 4;

var scrollAllObservable = client.ScrollAll<MyDocument>("30s", numberOfSlices);

Exception exception = null;
var manualResetEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);

var scrollAllObserver = new ScrollAllObserver<MyDocument>(
    onNext: s => 
    {
        var documents = s.SearchResponse.Documents;

        foreach (var document in documents)
        {
            // do something with this set of documents
        }
    },
    onError: e =>
    {
        exception = e;
        manualResetEvent.Set();
    },
    onCompleted: () => manualResetEvent.Set()
);

scrollAllObservable.Subscribe(scrollAllObserver);

manualResetEvent.WaitOne();

if (exception != null)
    throw exception;
```

If you don't need all of the control over the observer, you can use the simplified version. With this, you do need to specify a maximum run time for the overall operation though

```
var numberOfSlices = 4;

var scrollAllObservable = client.ScrollAll<MyDocument>("30s", numberOfSlices)
    .Wait(TimeSpan.FromHours(2), onNext: s =>
        {
           var documents = s.SearchResponse.Documents;

           foreach (var document in documents)
           {
                // do something with this set of documents
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks a ton. What if I need to map the outer dictionary of _source i.e. hits._index, hits._type, hits._id, hits._score and hits._source ? It might be needed to fetch both the outer hits._id values before retrieving the _source key-val pairs. any documentation links for that ?

Comment: You don't need to map those, the client will deserialize those for you. Take a look at `searchResponse.Hits` for metadata about each of the hits.