# Unable to fetch nested key-val pairs dictionary from elastic client search response

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, visual-studio-2015, nest

I am trying, but failing to access the hits["_index"], hits["_type"], hits["_id"], hits["_score"] and hits["_source"] from the below mentioned dictionary to load into a db.

Trying to access every key-val pair below:

```
{
  "took" : 12,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },

  **"hits" : {
    "total" : 2700881,
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "test_index",
        "_type" : "doc",
        "_id" : "R22224!!5333e7e4-9ee3-45f4-9dc3-2a8b8d8cdcf8",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "duration" : 14986283,
          "group_id" : "com",
          "var_time" : "2018-04-24T17:05:13.082+02:00",
          "var_name" : "2",
        }
      }
    ]
  }**
}
```

Things I tried:

Tried the below c# code and reviewed following urls:

[Unable to fetch _source dictionary key-val from elastic client search response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54151146/unable-to-fetch-source-dictionary-key-val-from-elastic-client-search-response/54164993)
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/auto-map.html

```
public class HitsDocument
{

    [PropertyName("_index")]
    public string Hitsindex { get; set; }

    [PropertyName("_type")]
    public string Hitstype { get; set; }

    [PropertyName("_id")]
    public string Hitsid { get; set; }

    [PropertyName("_score")]
    public string Hitsscore { get; set; }

    [PropertyName("_source")]
    public RawDocument Hitssource { get; set; }

}

public class RawDocument
{

    [PropertyName("duration")]
    public long Duration { get; set; }

    [PropertyName("group_id")]
    public string GroupId { get; set; }

    [PropertyName("var_time")]
    public DateTime Vartime { get; set; }

    [PropertyName("var_name")]
    public string Varname { get; set; }

}

static void Main(string[] args)
{

    var pool = new SingleNodeConnectionPool(new Uri("http://localhost:9200"));

    var settings = new ConnectionSettings(pool)
        .DefaultMappingFor<HitsDocument>(m => m
              .IndexName("test_index")
              .TypeName("doc"));

    var searchResponse = client.Search<HitsDocument>();

    var numberOfSlices = 4;


    var scrollAllObservable = client.ScrollAll<HitsDocument>("3m", numberOfSlices)
        .Wait(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5), onNext: s =>
    {

        var docs = s.SearchResponse.DebugInformation;
        var documents = s.SearchResponse.Hits;

        foreach (var document in documents)
            {
                    // do something with this set of documents
                    // business logic to load into the database.

                MessageBox.Show("document.Id=" + document.Id);
                MessageBox.Show("document.Score=" + document.Score);
                MessageBox.Show("document.Source=" + document.Source);
                MessageBox.Show("document.Type=" + document.Type);
                MessageBox.Show("document.Index=" + document.Index);
        }
        });

}
```

What am I doing wrong and also please point me in direction of documentation that betters my understanding of the API client for nested dictionary?

Thanks in advance.

**Update:**
The following code solution originally answered by @Russ Cam in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54151146/unable-to-fetch-source-dictionary-key-val-from-elastic-client-search-response) answers it.
I failed to realize it before.

```
public class RawDocument
{

    [PropertyName("duration")]
    public long Duration { get; set; }

    [PropertyName("group_id")]
    public string GroupId { get; set; }

    [PropertyName("var_time")]
    public DateTime Vartime { get; set; }

    [PropertyName("var_name")]
    public string Varname { get; set; }

}

static void Main(string[] args)
{

    var pool = new SingleNodeConnectionPool(new Uri("http://localhost:9200"));

    var settings = new ConnectionSettings(pool)
        .DefaultMappingFor<RawDocument>(m => m
              .IndexName("test_index")
              .TypeName("doc"));

    var searchResponse = client.Search<RawDocument>();

    var numberOfSlices = 4;


    var scrollAllObservable = client.ScrollAll<RawDocument>("3m", numberOfSlices)
        .Wait(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5), onNext: s =>
    {

        var docs = s.SearchResponse.DebugInformation;
        var documents = s.SearchResponse.Hits;

        foreach (var document in documents)
            {
                    // do something with this set of documents
                    // business logic to load into the database.

                MessageBox.Show("document.Id=" + document.Id);
                MessageBox.Show("document.Score=" + document.Score);
                MessageBox.Show("document.Source.duration=" + document.Source.duration);
                MessageBox.Show("document.Source.var_time=" + document.Source.var_time);
                MessageBox.Show("document.Source.var_name=" + document.Source.var_name);
                MessageBox.Show("document.Type=" + document.Type);
                MessageBox.Show("document.Index=" + document.Index);
        }
        });

}
```

Comment: I haven't tried, but, shouldn't you read from root?

Comment: Might be worth adding your `Update` as an answer below, and accepting it. This would help others out with a similar question in the future :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As point by @Russ Cam, the below solution update is being posted as an answer for others to review.

```
public class RawDocument
{

    [PropertyName("duration")]
    public long Duration { get; set; }

    [PropertyName("group_id")]
    public string GroupId { get; set; }

    [PropertyName("var_time")]
    public DateTime Vartime { get; set; }

    [PropertyName("var_name")]
    public string Varname { get; set; }

}

static void Main(string[] args)
{

    var pool = new SingleNodeConnectionPool(new Uri("http://localhost:9200"));

    var settings = new ConnectionSettings(pool)
        .DefaultMappingFor<RawDocument>(m => m
              .IndexName("test_index")
              .TypeName("doc"));

    var searchResponse = client.Search<RawDocument>();

    var numberOfSlices = 4;


    var scrollAllObservable = client.ScrollAll<RawDocument>("3m", numberOfSlices)
        .Wait(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5), onNext: s =>
    {

        var docs = s.SearchResponse.DebugInformation;
        var documents = s.SearchResponse.Hits;

        foreach (var document in documents)
            {
                    // do something with this set of documents
                    // business logic to load into the database.

                MessageBox.Show("document.Id=" + document.Id);
                MessageBox.Show("document.Score=" + document.Score);
                MessageBox.Show("document.Source.duration=" + document.Source.duration);
                MessageBox.Show("document.Source.var_time=" + document.Source.var_time);
                MessageBox.Show("document.Source.var_name=" + document.Source.var_name);
                MessageBox.Show("document.Type=" + document.Type);
                MessageBox.Show("document.Index=" + document.Index);
        }
        });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

An idea:

First, read from root, create map classes from root. Took, TimedOut, Shards and Hits.

Second, your classes are intended for "hits.hits". And this is an array, so it needs an IEnumerable like List. Please finish this by yourself by adding [PropertyName("...")] as needed:

```
public class OuterHits
{
  public string total {get;Set;}

  public string max_score {get;Set;}

  public List<RawDocument> hits {get;Set;} // or hits[]
}
```

Also you may need a root class

```
public class rootClass
{
public string string took {get;Set;}
public string timeout {get;Set;}
public Shards shards {get;Set;}
public OuterHits hits {get;Set;}
}
```

Also implement Shards class

Comment: Hi @Jorge Rojas. Like you mentioned, I tried implementing the inherited class structure. I am able to access hits["_index"], hits["_type"], hits["_id"], hits["_score"] but not hits["_source"] which returns null.  I am able to either fetch both levels of the dictionary separately but not in a class hierarchical structure.